# How do I grant consent to SharePoint Delegated Permissions in Word Online Addin using Azure Active Directory V2?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, office-js, sharepoint-online

I originally posted the following on github: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/323, but they suggested I post on stack overflow.

I have an Azure Active Directory v2 application which lists some SharePoint delegated permissions: 
[image]

I have a Word Online Addin that uses the V2 app.  I tried adding the SharePoint permissions as scopes in the Office Manifest such as

```
<Scope>AllSites.Read</Scope>
```

However, I get the following message after attempting to grant consent inside Word Online:

[image]

Is this error expected? Ultimately I wanted to enable single sign on in Office (Similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins but for CSOM, not Graph).  I was able to get this to work for Graph permissions.

Comment: In the flow you're currently using for login are you able to supply what endpoint you want to connect to?  I have a hypothesis that the getAccessTokenAsync method may be hard coded to request Microsoft Graph context and that we need to get you a method to request a SharePoint context instead.  I'm going to keep following up internally until we have a solid answer for you, but wanted to get things going with that question.

Comment: Hi I work with @JBart. We're not oauth experts by any means so I'm not sure what you mean by supplying the endpoint. I've been doing a bunch of experiments lately with SSO trying to get our backend service to impersonate a 365 user and route documents to sharepoint on their behalf. I haven't had any luck properly authenticating via CSOM. I tried MSAL and the tutorial in the below comment and neither worked for me. I get back generic errors like 403 forbidden and whatever I google I hit brick walls. Super frustrating.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243915/sharepoint-o365-csom-web-application-with-sso-authentication-service-account

Answer (score 2):

First, let me clarify that the SSO API is still in-preview. In production, you should be using [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) to login the user but it does not provide SSO. 
Now coming to the in-preview SSO API - Have you tried any of the SharePoint scopes owned by Graph? Adding that to the manifest should work. Currently, we do not support any other scope other than Graph. But there is no reason why the same token can be used to access SharePoint provided you use Graph scopes.

Comment: I did try adding sharepoint scopes owned by Graph, but always 401 error when using CSOM.  With fiddler some more error info: 
x-ms-diagnostics: 3000006;reason="Token contains invalid signature.";category="invalid_client"
{"error_description":"Invalid issuer or signature."}

And the same token does work for Graph requests

Comment: Which token are you using to access Graph? As documented here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet, as part of OBO, you need to swap your access token for an access token that allows you to access Graph.

Comment: We are swapping the token  here: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token.  The token we receive works fine for accessing SharePoint via graph OBO, but does not work for CSOM as a bearer token - is this token expected to work for CSOM?